# pdo binding returns false in update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have some issues with an update script. I bind my values but it returns false and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

I am running this:

```
$row = $db->query('
            UPDATE '. $config->db_prefix .'_adverts
            SET ad_type = ?, 
            title = ?, 
            text = ?, 
            price = ?, 
            category = ?, 
            condition = ?
            WHERE aid = ?')
                ->bind(1, $ad_type)
                ->bind(2, $title)
                ->bind(3, $text)
                ->bind(4, $price)
                ->bind(5, $category)
                ->bind(6, $condition)
                ->bind(7, $aid)->execute();
        }
```

The bind function is this:

```
public function bind($pos, $value, $type = null) {

        if( is_null($type) ) {

            switch( true ) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }

        $this->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
        return $this;
    }
```

a `var_dump($this)` gives me:

```
object(DB)#1 (2) { ["dbh":protected]=> object(PDO)#2 (0) { } ["stmt":protected]=> object(PDOStatement)#15 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(211) " UPDATE rno_adverts SET ad_type = ?, title = ?, text = ?, price = ?, category = ?, condition = ? WHERE aid = ?" } }
```

but I can't see what is wrong.

EDIT:

query function is this:

```
public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        return $this;
    }
```

and execute is this:

```
public function execute($var = null) {
        return $this->stmt->execute($var);
    }
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition = 3 WHERE aid = 1'
```

The output of the query:

```
UPDATE rno_adverts SET ad_type = 3, title = "Gul bil", text = "En flot gul bil med hvide striber", price = 500, category = 4, condition = 3 WHERE aid = 1
```

I have gone blind on this query so I can't see what the problem is. If I remove category and condition, it works without problems. Both fields are INT NOT NULL in the database.

Comment: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: If `PDOStatement::execute()` returns `FALSE` you should not conclude that you do something wrong because it is a valid return value of that function. It just means that there was a failure with the statement and the statement itself contains the information what the error was. Just pick the error info http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php it tells you more about the failure. So instead of telling in your question only about FALSE (which can mean a lot) you should provide the concrete error information.

Comment: Should notice that above pdo scripts is not my work. Found it here on SO - can't find the thread.

Question updated with error

Comment: this set of functions is quite useless to my opinion. why not to use raw PDO?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - So you're saying that I don't need to use this set of functions and instead use the PDO from within f.x. my single advert update function ( update_advert() )?

Comment: Garh.. found the issue on this one! I was using "condition" in the statement - reserved word!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of this bind function and be all right

```
$sql = 'UPDATE '. $config->db_prefix .'_adverts SET 
        ad_type = ?, title = ?, text = ?, price = ?, category = ?, condition = ?
        WHERE aid = ?';
$db->query($sql);
$db->execute(array($ad_type, $title, $text, $price, $category, $condition, $aid));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the bind functions with prepared statements. `->query()` is for generating queries where you already know all the values/variables of a query beforehand.

Comment: He's still using `PDO::query` with placeholders. Does not make sense to me.

Comment: One reason to not name a `prepare` method `query` probably. I guess OP tries to create a fluent interface.

Comment: He's not using `PDO::query()`, it's his own code that returns a statement.

Answer (score -1):

From your question one can not say specifically where the error is located. I therefore suggest you add more error checks first, e.g. with `bindvalue()`, you don't check the return value:

```
$this->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
```

Instead throw an exception if this failed:

```
$bind = $this->stmt->bindValue($pos, $value, $type);
if (!$bind) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf("Unable to bind parameter %s with a value of type #%d", $pos, $type));
}
```

This will prevent you have problems binding a value but it got unnoticed.

Similar with the execution. If you want to provide information why it fails, you need to read out the error information and throw an exception.